# How to use condition if into assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have an html template and there is a code with condition  **-->**

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>

    <!-- <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
   </script>
   <![endif]-->
```

I'd like to know how to use this **if** into this assetic

```
{% block Javascript %}
    {% javascripts output='js/dashboard/main.js' filter='?yui_js'
    'dashboard/js/date-time/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why not just put this code inside your javascript block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just use this **if** you can just put this code into block:

```
{% block Javascript %}
    <!--[if !IE]> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>

    <!-- <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
   </script>
   <![endif]-->
    {% javascripts output='js/dashboard/main.js' filter='?yui_js'
    'dashboard/js/date-time/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you want to compile your `jquery.min.js` with other script into one file you need something like that:

```
{% block Javascript %}
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    {% javascripts output='js/dashboard/main.js' filter='?yui_js'
    'dashboard/js/date-time/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'
    'assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='{{ asset_url }}'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    <!-- <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
    {% javascripts output='js/dashboard/main-ie.js' filter='?yui_js'
    'dashboard/js/date-time/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'
    'assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='{{ asset_url }}'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
   <![endif]-->

{% endblock %}
```